# Linux Terminal writing json but enter produces only a new line how to run the command

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, terminal

i am using the Linux terminal to formulate an AWS command. After the command i have to specify the config via JSON.
So i am writing the JSON and want to trigger the command but whenever i press enter it only gives me a new line.

I am not using a specific **text editor** in the **terminal**.
I know this is a stupid question but i am searching now for an hour but i cant find the correct shortcut. I would really appreciate if somebody could give me a hint.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at you quotation marks If they are closed properly, it wont give you a new line.

Comment: @EwNa can you send the command that you have typed and what youre trying to type?

Comment: POST /wireless-devices/f6836b05-ebb4-0000-1111-b6d21999793a/data HTTP/1.1
lease enter content (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) to be POSTed:  {
   "PayloadData": "0203000000f873450",
   "TransmitMode": 1,
   "WirelessMetadata": {
      "LoRaWAN": {
         "FPort": 1
      },
      "Sidewalk": {
         "MessageType": "string",
         "Seq": number
      }
   }
} Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: ```"Seq": number``` shouldnt the **number** be in double quotes too?

Comment: yeah i changed it but there isnt any difference. If the json is wrong than i should get an error response. But i cannot even send the command.

Comment: Hey Kashish did you face the same issue? Or is it working just fine on your side?